# Can't seem to get CakePHP's AuthComponent working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm completely lost in trying to setup the AuthComponent.
Every login fails.

Here's my AppController `beforeFilter` function:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'all' => array(
            'userModel' => 'ClientUser',
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'login',
                'password' => 'password'
            )
        )
    );

    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'client_users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'static', 'action' => 'clientcenter');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'static', 'action' => 'home');

    // I deny stuff later on
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

And here's the `login` function in the ClientUsers controller:

```
public function login() {

    // Check login data
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
}
```

And it always fails. And I have no idea why.

This is my `$request->data` content: (I've actually used "login" and "username" as field name, none work)

```
ClientUser
    login: user@email.com
    password: thepassword
```

Client passwords are hashed in the Model, using the authcomponent (which is imported at the top of the script. I used the security hash function earlier, but that also did not work):

```
public function beforeSave($options) {

    $this->data['ClientUser']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['ClientUser']['password1']);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "this->Auth->allow();" is a bad idea. Only whitelist certain action or at least put this only in some controllers, never in the app controller. also, your beforeSave looks bad (even though it will most likely be unrelated). How do you include the AuthComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is you Auth adapter?
as explained on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authentication-objects

```
// at least one adapter is necessary (here Form)
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Somehow I thought that `Form` was the default adapter, this did indeed fix it.